# Is there a utility to encrypt a file with a key I created?

Tags: encryption

I'd like to encrypt a file (using AES 256) with a key that I create and manage myself.  Is there any linux command line utilty that supports this?  `gpg` does not, and I don't think `openssl` does either?

FYI I'm fully aware that creating and managing keys yourself is *not* considered secure or best practice.  Nevertheless, for my own idiosyncratic reasons, that's what I want to do.  If all else fails, I can write something in java to do this, but if there's an existing utility, I'd rather use it.

Comment: I think you will have to be a little more specific. Why can't you do what you want to do with gpg?

Comment: You could try ccencrypt

Answer (score 2):

gpg does support AES256, you just need to change the config file, there are options for setting preferred cipher, and there are options at encryption time.

gpg advises against setting the encryption cipher as it auto-selects based on preference and to maximize compatibility there are a number of supported ciphers.

here you can see the ciphers supported:

```
mike@mike-laptop4:~$ gpg --cipher-algo name --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.3-beta
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/mike/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

and again with disabled ciphers:

```
mike@mike-laptop4:~$ gpg --cipher-algo name --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.3-beta
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/mike/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: AES256, CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: I wasn't clear.  gpg supports AES, but not supplying you own key.

Comment: A passphrase is not the same as a key.  The passphrase gives you access to the keystore, which contains the key, which is generated by gpg.  I'm looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt without a key management system.

Comment: then just use what i typed for you without the "--passphrase KEY" part and it'll ask you for a key,passphrase,secretword,whatever *without* key management (system), e.g.:   gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 filename

Answer (score 0):

Check out mcrypt based on your description it should do as you require. As it allows you to use your own keys. Though I'm not sure why you can't use gpg?  TinyCA is another option if you are trying to use this encryption for the web or signing software.

You already noted that you understand the caveats of self signing so I'll leave that to your judgement.

Answer (score 0):

The `openssl` command line utility can do that, using a password from a file:

```
openssl aes-256-ctr -pass file:./passwordfile < file.plain > file.enc

openssl aes-256-ctr -d -pass file:./passwordfile < file.enc > file.plain
```

You could use `-K` to set the actual key used, instead of deriving it from a password, but then it requires setting the IV manually, too, so that's not very handy.

The manual page is [`enc(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enc).